# Is there a way that I can use sprintf() to limit a line/field size?

Tags: php, printf

I wrote the following bit of code and was wondering if there is a way that I can limit a field's size so that it doesn't overflow outside of the bounds of the line and wrap around into a new line.?

```
echo "Category    Product Selected" . "\n";
echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"."\n";
foreach ($category_page as $key => $value) {
    echo sprintf("%8s    %s",$key,$value) . "\n";
}
```

Bear in mind that this is being formatted for a plain text email/file.

Comment: fixed max character length ?

Comment: Won't using fixed character length force it to right alignment?

Comment: Wait started using it, only problem is that the string is now cutoff.

Comment: well yes, if not cutoff then what? wrapped?

Comment: Yes wrapped around if possible. Bear in mind this is being forward for an email/plain text.

Comment: No. `sprintf()` does not do wrapping.

Comment: take the formatted string and parse it in to wordwrap()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Dagon.

```
echo "Category    Product Selected" . "\n";
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"."\n";
foreach ($category_list as $key => $value) {
    $wrap_value = wordwrap($value, 60, "\n            ", TRUE);
    echo sprintf("%8s    %s",$key,$wrap_value) . "\n";
}
```

I didn't know how to add in as spaces easily so I just added it against the newline.

Sample output:

```
Category    Product Selected
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1    4386,4387
       4    14,6,23,16,17
       5    309,335,323,331,313
       6    1004,1003,997,996,1002,1004,1003,997,996,1002,1004,1003,997,
            996,1002,1004,1003,997,996,1002,1004,1003,997,996,1002,1004,
            1003,997,996,1002,1004,1003,997,996,1002,1004,1003,997,996,1
            002,1004,1003,997,996,1002,1004,1003,997,996,1002,1004,1003,
            997,996,1002,1004,1003,997,996,1002,
       7    154,52,124,85,88
       8    266,253,224,180,209
       9    278,284,276,291,275
      10    297
```

Answer (score 0):

This, cut the text with more than 20 characters.

```
printf("%8s    %.20s\n",$key, $value);
```

Comment: I think is not possible to do with a single printf. But It could be possible using a iteration to wrap the text.

Comment: The answer did lie in `sprintf` but using a wordwrap and sprintf combo helped out.